# Angular JS and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

How can we use angular JS in asp.net MVC. Still I couldn't understand the what is the advantage of using angular JS than razor controls, since we are able to use c# in the razor, UI development is faster than using html and javascript. Also we have brilliant functionality as Ajax.BeginForm() and Ajax.ActionLink(). Can some one explains what is the advantage of angular JS over cshtml?

Comment: *"UI development is faster"* ... that is totally debatable and an apples to oranges comparison

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, I personally do not think  using AngularJS with asp.net MVC is a good practice. If you are planning to start a new project, Use AngularJS with ASP.NET Web APIs

Now about advantages.
The best benefit of using AngularJS is reusable code.
HTML, Services, directives are all reusable features of angularJS where a developer has a very good handle on every variable that are used.

Using directives we can actually have reusable elements in AngularJS which can be used in any page of the application.
Using Services to call an API from front end makes it possible to have that API call to be coded only once in the Front end Application rather than jQuery.ajax Request for each API calls.

From the user Experience perspective,

AngularJS can provide a very Dynamic Single Page Application unlike ASP.NET MVC where ther will be constant page loading on each URL change
A developer can handle some of the business requirement form the front end side as well. Unlike MVC where everything is handled server side and there will be constant traffic of data communication from client to server.

Comment: In other words...think of back end and front end as completely different  apps with complete separation of concerns

Comment: But while in terms of effort razor is a best option right?

Comment: What do you mean by effort?

Comment: Time which is taking for the UI development.

Comment: Once you have an front end architecture set up in Angular JS (This takes AngularJS knowledge.), effort is less for UI development using AngularJS. 
Otherwise Visual Studio has direct option to create view for MVC application